# Shell Script - Pair numbers with a for statement

Tags: bash, shell, numbers

I'm trying to make a script that adds pairs of number, **using only simple for/if statements**, for example:

```
./pair 1 2 4 8 16
```

would result in

```
./pair 1 2 4 8 16 32
3
12
48
```

My current script is (probably hugely wrong, I'm new to Shell Scripting):

```
#!/bin/sh

sum=0
count=0

for a in $*
do
    sum=`expr $sum + $a`
    count=`expr $count + 1`

    if [ count=2 ]
        then
        sum=0
        count=0
    fi

    echo "$sum"

done

exit
```

However this is not working. Any help would be great.

Comment: Your question is tagged as `bash` but you have a bourne shell shebang line. Which are you actually targeting?

Comment: my terminal states `bash-4.1$`, the shebang line we were instructed to include by the tutor so I have no idea about that. @FatalError

Comment: @Acterveid: It's a common point of confusion for those new to shell scripting, but `/bin/sh` is not the same as `/bin/bash`. If you want to target bash your shebang line should read like `#!/bin/bash`. Otherwise, you'll find that some commands that work fine in your shell fail in your script.

Comment: @FatalError This is really quite common. In fact, on most systems, the _Bourne shell_ (`/bin/sh`) is really now just the BASH shell. I know my Mac's `/bin/sh` has history substitution, the `[[ ... ]]` test, variable arrays, and many other features never found in Bourne, but are BASH standards.

Comment: @DavidW. While that is true, `bash` will behave differently if it is invoked as `sh` vs. `bash` - it sets some defaults differently to be more compatible with Bourne shell. So even though it is technically the same program, it doesn't necessarily produce the same results, unless the user is careful to take those differences into account...

Comment: @DavidW `/bin/sh` isn't really the Bourne shell anymore; the name has been co-opted as the POSIX shell, which is richer than the original Bourne shell that used to use the name. Systems are free to make `/bin/sh` a link to any shell which implements the POSIX specification.

Comment: @chepner If you look at `/bin/sh` on most systems, you'll find it's a hard link to `/bin/bash`. BASH mentions that it follows POSIX conventions when invoked as `sh`, but most people would be hard pressed to name a full fledge BASH feature that wouldn't work in a shell script running in POSIX mode.

Comment: @DavidW: On many systems yes, but there are a fair number (e.g. [ubuntu after 6.10](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DashAsBinSh)) where /bin/sh is actually dash (a bare-minimum POSIX shell). If you specify `#!/bin/sh`, you cannot rely on any bash extensions being available.

Comment: @DavidW. I can name plenty of `bash` features that aren't guaranteed to work in *any* POSIX compliant shell: arrays, the `((…))` command, the `[[…]]` command, brace expansion, process substitution, certain parameter expansion operators…, all of which I have seen people try to use with `dash`. The question isn't whether the shell cheats by accepting non-POSIX features in POSIX mode, but whether *other* shells will accept them in POSIX mode, all of which kind of defeats the purpose of POSIX mode to some extent.

Comment: The `((...))`, `[[...]]`, brace expansion ( i.e. `${foo:-bar}`, `${foo:=bar}`, and even `${foo##bar}` are supported in BASH run in POSIX mode. These are all part of the [POSIX shell definition](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html. Arrays may not be supported, and BASH regular expression matching may not be supported, but I've found few shell scripts that actually use them. Even [dash](http://man.cx/dash) support almost all of these except the `[[ ... ]]` tests -- which I still rarely see in shell scripts even though it's suppose to be preferred.

Answer (score 3):

A `for` loop isn't really the right tool for this. Use a `while` loop and the `shift` command.

```sh
while [ $# -gt 1 ]; do
    echo $(( $1 + $2 ))
    shift 2
done
```

---

The problem in your script is that you do not have sufficient whitespace in your `if` statement, as well as not preceding the variable name with a `$`:

```
if [ $count = 2 ]
```

Also, you only want to output `$sum` just before you reset its value to 0, not every time through the loop.

And, `expr` isn't needed for arithmetic anymore: `sum=$(( sum + a ))`

Comment: That's what I originally answered, however the exercise states to use methods that were used in an example, which were:

case
for
if

My original solution was almost identical to yours and worked, however the specification requires that I use the techniques stated above.

Comment: @Chepner: I'd test : `[ $# -gt 1]` (and not 0) ... as you need a "$2" in your loop

Comment: `while [ $# > 1 ]` won't work. Use `while [ $# -gt 1 ]` or even better use `while (( $# > 1 ))`

Comment: I wanted to stick with standard `[…]` for this answer, but usually use `((…))` myself, which is why I forgot to switch to `-gt`. Thanks.

Comment: @chepner A good answer. I like the `while`, but officially in `/bin/sh`, you don't have the `let` statement or the `$((...))` arithmetic. Although I pointed out that on most systems `/bin/sh` is the BASH shell, you're better off using `expr` which is always available in pure Bourne shell rather than BASHisms. Rock (and write shell scripts) is if it's 1985.

Comment: `$((…))` is [in the POSIX spec](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_04). If your system's `/bin/sh` doesn't support it, it's not POSIX-compliant.

Answer (score 1):

> My approach uses cshell. As a C programmer, I connect better with cshell. But that asside, I approach the problem with an iterator, incrementing twice.
>   [macetw](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19659793/368630)

I haven't seen anyone write in Csh for a long time. Back in the early Unix days, there were two primary shells: Csh and Bourne shell. Bourne was the AT&T flavor and BSD (Berkeley Standard Distribution) used Csh which took syntax hints from the C language.

Most people I knew used Csh as their standard shell, but wrote scripts in Bourne shell because Csh had all sorts of issues as pointed out by [Tom Christiansen](http://www-uxsup.csx.cam.ac.uk/misc/csh.html) (as already mentioned by Olivier Dulac). However, Csh had command aliases and command line history and editing. Features that people wanted in their command line shell.

Csh peaked back in the SunOS days. SunOS was based upon BSD and Sun administrators wrote almost all  of their scripts in Csh. However, David Korn changed a lot of that with Kornshell. Kornshell contained the standard Bournshell syntax language, but contained features like command aliasing and shell history editing that people wanted in Csh. Not only that, but it contained a lot of new features that were never previously found in shells like built in math (goodbye to `expr` and `bc`), pattern matching with `[[ ... ]]` and shell options that could be set with `set -o`.

Now, there was little need to know Csh at all. You could use Kornshell as both your scripting language and your command line shell.  When Sun replaced SunOS with Solaris, the Kornshell and not the C shell was the default shell. That was the end of C shell as a viable shell choice.

The last big advocate of Csh was Steve Jobs. NeXT used the TurboCsh as its default shell, and it was the default shell on the first iteration of Mac OS X -- long after Sun had abandoned it. However, later versions of Mac OS X defaulted to BASH.

BASH is now the default and standard. As I mentioned before, on most systems, `/bin/sh` is *BASH*. In the BASH manpage is this:

> If bash is invoked with the name sh, it tries to mimic the startup behavior of historical versions of sh as closely as possible, ***while conforming to the POSIX standard as well***.

That means that solid BASHisms (`shopt`, `${foo/re/repl}`, etc.) are not active, but most of the stuff inherited from Kornshell (`[[ ... ]]`, `set -o`, `typeset`, `$(( ... ))` ) are still available. And, that means about 99% of the BASH scripts will still work even if invoked as `/bin/sh`.

I believe that most of the criticisms in Tom Christiansen anti-Csh paper no longer apply. Turbo C shell - which long ago replaced the original C shell fixed many of the bugs. However, Turbo C came after much of the world abandoned C shell, so I really can't say.

The Csh approach is interesting, but is not a correct answer to this question. C Shell scripting is a completely different language than Bourne shell. You'd be better off giving an answer in Python.

Comment: "This comment is interesting, but is not a correct answer to this question. Comments are a completely different entity than Answers. You'd be better off giving a comment below their answer" ;^)

Answer (score 0):

My approach uses cshell. As a C programmer, I connect better with cshell. But that asside, I approach the problem with an iterator, incrementing twice.

```
@ i = 1
while ( $i < $#argv )
  @ j = $i + 1
  @ sum = $argv[$i] + $argv[$j]
  echo $sum
  @ i = $i + 2
end
```

Comment: Why are you addressing your preference, as opposed to the shell the OP is actually using?

Comment: @macetw: Please don't take this the wrong way, but I wouldn't recommend anyone (especially new to scripting) to use csh for scripts: To those who want to know why, please read the infamous **[Csh Programming Considered Harmful](http://www-uxsup.csx.cam.ac.uk/misc/csh.html)** which gives many eye-opening warnings about things broken in csh shells.

Comment: I haven't learned bash. I would not teach a bash solution, given my experience.

Answer (score 0):

So the shebangs inplies bourne shell, and if you start the script directly it will be the same as doing:

```
/bin/sh <your_script_name>
```

And the simplest loop I can think of would be this one:

```
while [ $# -gt 1 ]; do
  expr $1 + $2
  shift 2
done
```

It counts the input tokens and as long as you have more than 2 (the square brackets test) it adds the first and the second one displaying the result. `shift 2` means shifting the input two places (i.e. $1 and $2 are dropped and $n will be mapped to $n-2).

Answer (score 0):

If you want a funny `sh`/`bc` combo solution:

```
#!/bin/sh
printf "%s+%s\n" "$@" | bc
```

It's cool, `printf` takes care of the loop itself. `:)`

Of course, there are no error checkings whatsoever! it will work with floats too.

The same with `dc`:

```
#!/bin/sh
printf "%s %s+pc" "$@" | dc
```

but it won't work with negative numbers. For negative numbers, you could:

```
#!/bin/sh
printf "%s %s+pc" "${@/-/_}" | dc
```

And I just realized this is the shortest answer!